# Calling 2 ivy files sequentially

Tags: ant, ivy, ant-contrib

I'm trying to call 2 retrieves one after the other.

When my ivy_portlet.xml is present, the second call is not executed.

When my ivy_portlet.xml is not present the second call retrieves the content of ivy.xml

When the 2 files are there, only the first one is executed.

What am I missing?

```
    <if>
        <available file="${basedir}/ivy_portlet.xml" />
        <then>
            <echo message="Getting runtime portlet dependencies using Ivy project's configuration" />
            <ivy:retrieve pattern="${project.lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" file="${basedir}/ivy_portlet.xml"/>
        </then>
    </if>
    <if>
        <available file="${basedir}/ivy.xml" />
        <then>
            <echo message="Getting deps using Ivy project's configuration" />
            <ivy:retrieve pattern="${project.lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" file="${basedir}/ivy.xml"/>
        </then>
    </if>
```

Comment: Seems to me you're trying to manage different groups of dependencies? In that case configurations (within a single ivy file) would solve your problem in a more flexible manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the trick:

A call to resolve must be made when using a file name different from ivy.xml.

```
<ivy:resolve file="${rpm.homedir}/Builder/ivy_portlet.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ant code looks fine, I even tested it locally (without the ivy retrieve tasks) and both if statements executed.  When both files are present and the first ivy retrieve fires, does the retrieve complete successfully without error or failure?  Maybe it's getting short-circuited with a failure.  Seeing the logs could help here.

Comment: I take it the log helped in solving this?  Glad you got it working.